# Do the roots of a polynomial remain inside the unit circle if we make the coefficients all positive?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, polynomials

Suppose the roots $r_1, \dots, r_p$ of the polynomial

$$x^p + a_1 x^{p-1} + a_2 x^{p-2} + \dots + a_p$$

all lie inside the unit circle. Is it true that the the roots of the polynomial

$$x^p + |a_1| x^{p-1} + |a_2| x^{p-2} + \dots + |a_p|$$

will also lie inside the unit circle?

Comment: Reminds me of Gershgorin circle theorem .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  For instance, $$(x-1)^3(x+1)=x^4-2x^3+2x-1$$ has all its roots in the unit disk but $$x^4+2x^3+2x+1$$ does not (it has a root between $-3$ and $-2$).  If you want the roots of the original polynomial to be in the open unit disk, you can perturb this example slightly (for instance, $(x-0.9)^3(x+0.9)$ still has a root near $-2$ when you take absolute values of its coefficients).

Comment: Thank you! Is it true up to polynomials of order 3?

Comment: I think so, though I haven't worked out a full proof.  In low degrees you can learn quite a lot from the fact that the product of the roots is the constant term (up to sign) and the nonreal roots must come in conjugate pairs.